# Linkedin API Signing In Key Is Revealed

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'm working with linkedin's Sign In feature and this gets me pussled:
What happens when my API key is revealed for everyone ? Is it not a security problem ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
api_key: DXjUrY-9apre6gnyK080MpTIoIS4f38AleG08Y0kLM0DH2xeNQATIfDMuoisCMO_
onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
authorize: true
</script>
```

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/javascript-api-tutorial

Comment: That's just your appId there is no security concern there. You are also putting your domain on Linkedin app settings. Domain name also validated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.)** On Linkedin app settings page, you are giving domain name. Also you can give callback url

**2.)** When Linkedin js loaded, it is getting your referer url and sends requests and get back to url specified in `callback_url`

Linkedin and other companies like fb, twitter compares request domain and the one you specified in app setting page. If another person uses your js code by getting it from your source code, it won't work on another domain. Those communications are made on https protocol with Linkedin, it is not possible to snif your communication between Linkedin. So, calm donw and trust this structure, as I said above, Big companies that provides oauth(2) signin uses this method. For more details please refer [here](http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified)